# Strange exception from boost::lexical_cast with boost::filesystem

Tags: c++, boost

On RHEL7.4, boost 1.53,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main() {
    const string& s1 = "1024";
    cout << "test1:" << lexical_cast<unsigned int>(s1) << endl;

    filesystem::path p("1024");
    cout << "test2:" << lexical_cast<unsigned int>(p.filename().string()) << endl;

    const string& s2 = p.filename().string();
    cout << "test3:" << lexical_cast<unsigned int>(s2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code gives:

```
test1:1024
test2:1024
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_lexical_cast> >'
  what():  bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
zsh: abort      ./a.out
```

Maybe this is a lexical_cast's bug but someones knows why test3 fails? Especially, I can't understand different between test1 and 3.

Comment: @MikeKinghan that's false, and it appearing to work is coincidence: boost 1.58 [already had the same behaviour](https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/blob/boost-1.58.0/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp#L420) just as [1.53.0](https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/blob/boost-1.53.0/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp#L383) or indeed [1.66.0](https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/blob/boost-1.66.0/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp#L435) (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line creates a dangling reference:

```
const string& s2 = p.filename().string();
```

That's because on POSIX systems, `path::filename()` returns *a reference* to a member(!!!). Therefore, no lifetime extension occurs, as would have been if it had returned a temporary.

Now, because `filename()` returns a temporary `path()` the reference is no longer valid. Your program invokes Undefined Behaviour.

I'd suggest a fix like:

```
p = p.filename();
const string& s2 = p.string();
cout << "test3:" << lexical_cast<unsigned int>(s2) << endl;
```

Or

```
p = p.filename();
cout << "test3:" << lexical_cast<unsigned int>(p.string()) << endl;
```

Or even

```
cout << "test3:" << lexical_cast<unsigned int>(p.filename().string()) << endl;
```

Best of all would be to keep things simple:

```
std::string const s2 = p.filename().string();
cout << "test3:" << lexical_cast<unsigned int>(s2) << endl;
```

Comment: Good news: C++17 didn't copy this API design mistake http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string

Comment: Thanks. The last suggestion looks the most readable code for me. So this introduce a new API design question: should we return reference of member to avoid memory copying, or return copy of member to avoid this kind of dangling reference situation.

Comment: @HiroshiAraki Depends on the type of object represented. Clearly in this case I think the unexpected reference return is a bad idea (see [also my reasoning here](https://twitter.com/sehetw/status/971569447696830464)). Avoiding copying is an important options, but usually indicates (premature) optimization agenda.